# SharePoint Designer workflows not working when Visual Studio is installed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, visual-studio

I'm unable to open and edit SharePoint workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013.  However, when I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise from the machine, I was able to open and edit workflows just fine.  Has anyone else experienced this and knows of a possible solution so that I can have both programs on my machine?

Comment: I am having Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and SharePoint Designer run parallel. May I know the issue you are having when you try to edit the workflow?

Comment: When I try to open or edit a workflow I get the following: "Windows Workflow Foundation, part of .Net Framework 3.0, must be installed to use this feature."  Or sometimes it asks me to close and reopen Designer.

Answer (score 3):

As you described in the comment the error you might be getting because of cache issue.

You have to remove these cache files from 3 locations on your machine

**%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache**

**%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache**

**%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache**

You can refer the below post for additional reference

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/372ec877-ede0-4df3-9dda-fb056d9689fa/sharepoint-2013-designer-error-windows-workflow-foundation-part-of-net-framework-30-must-be?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score -1):

You need to install [Office Tools](https://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2015) for Visual Studio 2015.